# How do I add background image in streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

Currently I am using streamlit version `1.9.0`. I am facing difficulty while adding background image to my streamlit app. I tried the following code snippet, but the image cannot be seen in the background.

```
import base64
import streamlit as st


def get_base64(bin_file):
    with open(bin_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return base64.b64encode(data).decode()


def set_background(png_file):
    bin_str = get_base64(png_file)
    page_bg_img = '''
    <style>
    body {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,%s");
    background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    ''' % bin_str
    st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)

set_background('./images/background.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because of how Streamlit lays out the page. In Streamlit, the "body" element seems to be a div of class `stApp`. So, try switching your style block to use `.stApp` instead of `body`:

```py
def set_background(png_file):
    bin_str = get_base64(png_file)
    page_bg_img = '''
    <style>
    .stApp {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,%s");
    background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    ''' % bin_str
    st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```